# What are some methods that could do it like a pair of binoculars or a telescope would, without actually using either?

Tags: solar-eclipse, projection

I'm an astronomy enthusiast in highschool. A partial solar eclipse will be visible from my country in 9 days, but it will take place during a school day. What are some projection methods that'll provide me the same image quality and size as using binoculars/scope would, without actually using either?
I already have eclipse glasses, but not enough of them as I was put in charge of eclipse viewing that day.
I've seen articles about mirror projection, but I would it be as sharp, large and bright?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/21099/16685 You can also use pinhole projection, but if you want a sharp image, the image will be fairly small. Also see https://www.popastro.com/main_spa1/using-a-mirror-to-view-a-partial-eclipse/

Comment: Nothing will give you as sharp of an image as you'd get through a telescope, but there's really not a lot of detail to see, so a pinhole projection will show nearly the same image as a telescope.  You might want to think about what to project on to, a bright white surface you can move around, like a piece of foam core would be great.  But another piece of cardboard like a notebook cover will do fine in a pinch.

Comment: FWIW, the New Moon is at 2022-Oct-25 10:48:42 UTC, the maximum eclipse is ~11:00 https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=YES&EPHEM_TYPE=O&OBJ_DATA=NO&COMMAND=301&CENTER=%40399&APPARENT=REFRACTED&QUANTITIES=43&START_TIME=%272022-Oct-25+10%3A30%27&STOP_TIME=%272022-Oct-25+11%3A30%27&STEP_SIZE=5m